# Disk Partition failed -- invalid volume free block count

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I tried to partition my Disk but it failed with this message:

[image]

I have tried First Aid under Recovery and it said the First Aid is completed. However, the partition still failed. What should I do?

My specs:
Macbook pro 2015 Retina model.
8G RAM 256G SSD.
macOS Sierra

**[Edit]**

Under Recovery, I can only run First Aid on the disk not on the "Macintosh HD" volume because it is greyed out. Another thing to mention is I installed rEFInd on my Mac as I was planning to install Ubuntu alongside macOS. Is any of this relevant to my problem?

Comment: Please add a proper answer instead of writing *solved: (and some explanation)* in your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running it a second time? Often with "File system check exit code is 8", others have had success repairing a second or third time.

You may also try booting from the recovery partition and running doing the repair. You can boot from the recovery partition by restarting and holding down the Option key, then select the Recovery partition.

If you don't have a recovery partition, you can do an Iternet Recovery by hold down the Command Option R keys.

[Here is discussion on Apple's Communities forum.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7305111?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: I have tried many many times. Still cannot work it out. Actually under Recovery, I can only run first-aid on the disk not on the "Macintosh HD" volume. So is that the problem? Because under Recovery, the volume is in grey colour (not clickable).  And one thing to mention is I installed rEFInd on my mac. I am planing to install Ubuntu alongside macOS. Could those be the source of the error?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your Mac HD was greyed out. You need to select it first, then click 'Mount'.   You will then be able to select it and run First Aid.